# using [] in the caption of the subfigure

Tags: captions

The `subfigure` caption uses []. Because of that, I am unable to use [] in its caption.

```
\subfigure[ This [] is important]
```

How do I use the brackets in the caption of the subfigure?

Comment: The problem is that LaTeX views the closing bracket as the end of the short title (optional argument). As suggested by David Carlisle, you can hide the square bracket in a brace pair: `{]}` should do the trick. (David put the entire optional argument in braces, but this is not needed.)

Answer (score 20):

For (almost) any latex optional argument you can use `{}` as in

```
\subfigure[{This [] is important}]
```

To hide the inner `[]` from the argument scanning.